# Want to create a scrabble content in both directions in flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, scroll, grid, multiple-columns

How can I make a table of 15 * 10 boxes which is scrollable both horizontally and vertically.
I also want to give a unique key to access each grid.
Suggest me,How can I do it in Flutter.

I tried use of table,GridView.count and GridView.builder but not able to meet the result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try below sample

```
List<Widget> _buildCells(int count) {
    return List.generate(
      count,
          (index) => Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 120.0,
        height: 60.0,
        color: Colors.white,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Text("${index + 1}",),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildRows(int count) {
    return List.generate(
      count,
          (index) => Row(
        children: _buildCells(10),
      ),
    );
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Flutter Demo"),
          centerTitle: true,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: _buildRows(20),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
```